# Subtract value of double array element from the previous array element

Tags: java, arrays

I have retrieved values from a sqlite database into a double array. Suppose i have a double array like this:

```
double[] n = { 1.2, 3.0, 4.5, 6.7.... };
```

My aim is to perform the following calculations,

```
double total = (3.0 - 1.2) + (4.5 - 3.0) + (6.7 - 4.5) ...
```

The array values are from a database. How can i achieve this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop starting from index 1

```
double x = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  x += (array[i] - array[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer if it helped you out

Comment: @ma100,  `x = a[a.length-1]-a[0]` should give the same answer.

Comment: @james Thanks for the contribution